# Initialize ASP.NET MVC controller using current user ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created an ASP.NET MVC controller which responds with data from a data repository. The repository is pretty simple (underlying EF6 backend) and the data is specific to a user. So my actions typically look like this:

```
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository _repository = new MyDataContextRepository();

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult GetMyData()
        {
            var result = _repository.GetData(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```

But because I'll be using the user'd ID in nearly all the calls, I'd like to initialize the repository with the current user's ID instead, like so.

```
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository _repository = new MyDataContextRepository(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult GetMyData()
        {
            var result = _repository.GetData();
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that the constructor is run before the user's officially logged in, so the `GetUser()` looks for the username `""` (user not authorized yet).

Is it possible to initialize my data repository once after a user has been authenticated? Or can I only identify the user during the action method's call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard practice would say that you should pass the user ID to the repository methods as a parameter, rather than basing the whole repository upon it.

But if you want to do it how you are, you can wrap the `_repository` in a property and create it the first time it is called. A simple way to do this is to use the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class. In this way the constructor will only be called the first time the repository is actually used and the User should be available then:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private Lazy<IRepository> _repository = new Lazy<IRepository>(
        () => new MyDataContextRepository(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey));

    private IRepository Repository
    {
        get { return _repository.Value; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult GetMyData()
    {
        var result = Repository.GetData(); // the repository constructor will get called here
        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is really tidy.
I think I'll keep to standard practice in this case, but the use of Lazy<T> was a good find.